# Como puedo crear un acordeon dinamico con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando crear un acordeon dinamico con jquery que solo me permita tener un elemento abierto a la vez, cuando otro se abra, el anterior se cierra, por ahora solo he logrado hacer que se abra y que desaparezca el boton a la hora de abrirlo pero no puedo hacer que el anterior se cierre cuando se abra uno nuevo. La clase del boton para abrir es "vermas" y cuando se le da click cambia a "vermas active" y se despliega el contenido, como pudiera hacer para que se cierre el contenido cuando se abra uno nuevo? Espero su ayuda.

```
<?php
// Seccion relaciones publicas

$icono__relaciones__publicas  = get_field( 'icono__relaciones__publicas' );
$titulo__relaciones__publicas = get_field( 'titulo__relaciones__publicas' );
$texto__relaciones__publicas  = get_field( 'texto__relaciones__publicas' );

// Seccion proyectos destacados
$imagen__proyecto__destacado    = get_field( 'imagen__proyecto__destacado' );
$titulo__proyecto__destacado    = get_field( 'titulo__proyecto__destacado' );
$subtitulo__proyecto__destacado = get_field( 'subtitulo__proyecto__destacado' );
$texto__proyecto__destacado     = get_field( 'texto__proyecto__destacado' );

// Seccion algunos datos
$titulo__algunos__datos       = get_field( 'titulo__algunos__datos' );

// Seccion elige tu marca
$titulo__marca__noticia       = get_field( 'titulo__marca__noticia' );
$link__boton__marca__noticia  = get_field( 'link__boton__marca__noticia' );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'soluciones',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 15
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('template_parts/banner-servicios') ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- -->

            <div class="section__body__soluciones">

                <div class="container">

                    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                        
                    <div class="lista__servicios__reiva">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3">
                                <?php if (get_field('icono')): ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_field('icono') ?>" alt="" class="banner-graphic__ico">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 order-md-1">
                                <div class="content__servicios">
                                    <h3 class="c-overlay-big__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <div class="vermas">
                                        Ver más
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt-5" style="display: none;" >
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12">
                        <div class="lista__relaciones__publicas">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Estrategias de comunicación en medios de comunicación</li>
                                <li>Marketing de influencers</li>
                                <li>Prevención y manejo de crisis</li>
                                <li>Media training</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-12">
                        <div class="proyecto__destacado__publico">
                            <img src="<?php echo $imagen__proyecto__destacado; ?>" alt="">
                            <div class="proyecto__destacado">
                                <h3><?php echo $titulo__proyecto__destacado; ?></h3>
                                <h4><?php echo $subtitulo__proyecto__destacado; ?></h4>
                               <p class="contenidoslistaservicio">El evento cultural más importante del Perú se reinventa, llevando de manera virtual, cultura a todos los rincones del país.</p>
                                <a href="#"  class="btn__vermas">Saber más</a>
                            </div>
                            <br><br>
                            <!-- -->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- -->

                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <!-- -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- -->
                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                        <p>Datos vacios.</p>
                    <?php endif;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?> 

                </div>
                <!-- -->
                
            </div>
            <!-- -->

        </div>
        <!-- -->

    </section>

   
    <!-- -->

   <section class="seccion__marca__noticia">
        <div id="encabezado">
            <h4>Hagamos que tu<br>marca sea <span>noticia</span></h4>
            <a href="http://nomadasdigital.com/contacto/" class="btn__vermas">
                Conversemos
            </a>            
        </div>
        <!-- -->
        
    </section>
    <!-- -->

    <div id="scrollUp">
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/arrow-scroll.png" alt="">
    </div>


<script>    
  function main(){
  $(".row mt-5").hide();
  $(".proyecto__destacado__publico").fadeIn(2000);
  $(".row mt-5").hide();
  // button accordion toggle
$(".vermas").on("click", function(){
    //$(this).next().toggle();
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).hide();
});
}
$(document).ready(main);
    
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({ toggle: false });
    
</script>



<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hola. JQuery **ofrece un pluggin Accordion** entra a [JQueryUI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) y revísalo. Es muy fácil de usar. Si necesitas algo más complejo, puedes partir de ahí.

Comment: gracias @quevedo lo revisare.